# List PDF's From Directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, pdf

I have a folder that contains a bunch of PDF files. On the webpage I am creating I want to have a link to each of the PDF's. I have manually input every single link to every single PDF but obviously this is super inefficient.

```
<ul>
  <li><h1>2016</h1></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="./newsletters/2016/May 2016.pdf" target="_blank">May 2016</a></li>
      <li><a href="./newsletters/2016/March 25th, 2016.pdf" target="_blank">March 25th, 2016</a></li>
      <li><a href="./newsletters/2016/March  22nd, 2016.pdf" target="_blank">March  22nd, 2016</a></li>
      ...
    </ul>
    <li><h1>2015</h1></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="./newsletters/2015/September 25th 2015.pdf" target="_blank">September 25th 2015</a></li>
      <li><a href="./newsletters/2015/October 23rd 2015.pdf" target="_blank">October 23rd 2015</a></li>
      ...
```

And so on.

Is there anyway to turn this into some kind of loop that sticks the name of the file itself into the 'href', and also in between the `<a>` and `</a>` tags?

[image: List of PDFs Inside Folder]

Comment: Yes, but you will need some sort of server side language to actually read the directories and serve up the list. Do you have access to a server-side language?

Comment: You can achieve this easily using server side language. So are you able to use PHP code in your webpage?

Comment: @RahulPatel I'm using HTML/JS in my webpage, but the server apparently has ASP.NET installed. No PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could use a static file server. Check out these links:

https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-static

Since you do not have a server side language, this is the only option I can remember.